# Pre-setting values to Docusign template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi, httparty

I am new to Docusign api and I am trying to post values from my form into a template. To be honest, I am not sure if I even created the custom fields properly or if there is some special way to set them into the form other than just creating a text field with a name.

I have read through the docs and recipes and about a dozen or more stack posts.

I am using rails and my fields post just fine but it's my tabs that do not. I read somewhere that I am supposed to use tabs and not custom_fields. Not sure if that's totally correct but that's how I've interpreted it.

Here is my current code:

```
body:  {
            "emailSubject": "DocuSign API call - Request Signature - Boom",
            "templateId": "e1d5bce1-9757-4ffe-881b-054aa9139f2f",
            "templateRoles": [{
                "email": "#{renter.email}",
                "name": "#{renter.background.legal_name}",
                "roleName": "Lessee"
                },{
                "email": "#{@manager.email}",
                "name": "#{@manager.name}",
                "roleName": "Lessor",
                "tabs": {
                    "texttabs": [{
                                "tabLabel": "Rent",
                                "value": "#{@lease.rent}"
                                },{
                                "tabLabel": "Address",
                                "value": "987 apple lane"
                    }]
                }
            }],
            "status": "sent"
        }.to_json
```

baseUrl that I am sending to:

```
"https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/my_id/envelopes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with the code but with the setup within docusign. Make sure that you are setting up your tabs correctly and if you want to replicate a field multiple times make sure that they all share the same exact name.

Comment: If this is not a code problem, it should be deleted. It is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: This question has answers so it cannot be deleted. The code above is good to have as the documentation does not explain it well when working with rails.

Answer (score 0):

- In your texttabs section, you should be passing in the following parameters at a minimum per tab: tablabel & value.
- tablabel  is the name of the tab that you have defined on the template. So from what I can tell, you have a text box on your template called Address. So you should put "tablabel":"Address".
- value is what you would like to pre-populate in the tab. Looks like you have that correct.
- You do not want to use tabID as that is not a valid parameter in this flow. The API documentation details what parameters you can use: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm?Highlight=data%20tab
- I also see an extraneous parameter of "Rent" under templateRoles section. That value will be ignored since it is not a valid parameter.

Comment: I changed my code to "tabLabel" but still no luck. When I create the custom field in Docusign when editing the template am I supposed to do anything else other than selecting custom fields from the left nave menu -> new field -> then select type text and give it a name? Are there any other options I am supposed to select?

Comment: Envelope Custom Fields is metadata that can be associated and tied to a given envelope. This metadata cannot be used during the signing experience in any way. From what you are describing it sounds like you want to pre-populate values into DS text tabs during the signing experience.  Please post an updated snippet of your new JSON.

Comment: What I have done is upload a pdf to docusign templates, this pdf is a rental agreement. It populates all of the fields except for the custom fields only come through as input boxes which require a user to fill in. I would like to prepopulate those values and make them fixed similar to the name or date option on the standard fields.

Comment: I appreciate your time, help and patience